# Haskell : Possible cause: ‘(:)’ is applied to too many arguments

Tags: haskell, types

I‘ve created a nested function which fails at the third nesting. I fail to understand why this pattern holds up for the previous two nests but not the third. I'm attempting to recursively work through the list to add the items in the list together

```
module Nests 
(nest1,nest2,nest3) where

nest1 :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
nest1 _ [] = []
nest1 [] _ = []
nest1 (xs:ls1) (xt:ls2) = (xs+xt):nest1 ls1 ls2

nest2 :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
nest2 _ [] = []
nest2 [] _ = []
nest2 (xs:ls1) (xt:ls2) = (nest1 xs xt):nest2 ls1 ls2

nest3 :: (Num a) => [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
nest3 (xs:xt:ls)
    | length ls <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt):nest3 ls
```

where compiled:

```
nests.hs:17:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]’
                  with actual type ‘[[[a]]]’
    • Possible cause: ‘(:)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: (nest2 xs xt) : nest3 ls
      In an equation for ‘nest3’:
          nest3 (xs : xt : ls)
            | length ls <= 0 = []
            | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt) : nest3 ls
    • Relevant bindings include
        ls :: [[[a]]] (bound at nests.hs:15:14)
        xt :: [[a]] (bound at nests.hs:15:11)
        xs :: [[a]] (bound at nests.hs:15:8)
        nest3 :: [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] (bound at nests.hs:15:1)
   |
17 |     | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt):nest3 ls
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

nests.hs:17:33: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[[a]]]’
                  with actual type ‘[[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]’
    • Probable cause: ‘nest3’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘nest3 ls’
      In the expression: (nest2 xs xt) : nest3 ls
      In an equation for ‘nest3’:
          nest3 (xs : xt : ls)
            | length ls <= 0 = []
            | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt) : nest3 ls
    • Relevant bindings include
        ls :: [[[a]]] (bound at nests.hs:15:14)
        xt :: [[a]] (bound at nests.hs:15:11)
        xs :: [[a]] (bound at nests.hs:15:8)
        nest3 :: [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] (bound at nests.hs:15:1)
   |
17 |     | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt):nest3 ls
```

Comment: For a start, your recursive call to `nest3` has only 1 argument, not 2...

Comment: In the function, I have also provided only one argument, no? Is (xs:xt:ls) considered two arguments?

Comment: Yeah, why is that? The type signature says the function has 2 arguments, but you've only supplied one. You say "I fail to see why the pattern works for 1 and 2, but not 3", and yet, `nest3` looks markedly different to the other two functions. Why not just continue the same pattern?

Comment: Aren't these all supposed to be applications of `zipWith`? `nest1 = zipWith (+)`, `nest2 = zipWith nest1`, `nest3 = zipWith nest2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type annotation for `nest3` does not match its body.

`nest3 :: [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]` means that function takes two arguments before returning list but in the function's body you take just one argument.

You can need to fix type signature (or just drop it, GHC is able to infer it):

```
nest3 :: (Num a) => [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
nest3 (xs:xt:ls)
    | length ls <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = (nest2 xs xt):nest3 ls
```

---

The problem here is that the first error seems not very relevant. The second one clearly states that `nest3` expects one more argument.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[[[a]]]’
              with actual type ‘[[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]’
• Probable cause: ‘nest3’ is applied to too few arguments
```

But the first one suggest that `(:)` is used incorrectly.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]’
              with actual type ‘[[[a]]]’
• Possible cause: ‘(:)’ is applied to too many arguments
```

To understand why there are two errors and why the first one is so obscure, consider how GHC works. It tries both to infer types and match inferred types with type annotations provided by the programmer.

Knowing that `(:) :: b -> [b] -> [b]` we can *infer* that `nest3 ls` must be of type `[b]` in the expression `(..) : nest3 ls`. *Matching* this with the provided type `[[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]` gives the error `‘nest3’ is applied to too few arguments`.

Trying to *infer* type of the `otherwise` branch in `nest3` GHC considers again the type of `(:)`. Applied to two arguments `(:)` gives a list. *Matching* this with the provided `nest3` type gives `‘(:)’ is applied to too many arguments` because only by removing one of the arguments we can get an arrow type.

Comment: thank you, I forgot the type constraints the nest3.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question of why it says `‘(:)’ is applied to too many arguments`:

Since your type signature tells Haskell that the function takes two arguments, but you only match for one, it will interpret it as a function returning a function, kind of like in point free style

For example like this

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x = (+) x
```

which is equivalent to these

```
plus' :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus' x y = (+) x y
plus'' :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus'' = (+)
```

---

So, in this case, your function is equivalent to

```
nest3 :: (Num a) => [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
nest3 (xs:xt:ls) z
    | length ls <= 0 = [] z
    | otherwise = ((nest2 xs xt):nest3 ls) z
-- or
--  | otherwise = (:) (nest2 xs xt) (nest3 ls) z
```

Which explains why it thinks `(:)` might be applied to too many arguments.